# Django template if type add to html id

Tags: python, django, django-templates, dry

The model `gigi` has got a `typology` attribute, I want to add items into a html `div` tag based on the value of the `typology` attribute. How can I manage to do this in Djangos templates:

```
for gigi in object_list


<div id="typology1">
{%if gigi.typology == "typology1"> %}
   <div> {{gigi.name}}</div>
{% endif %}
</div>

<div id="typology2">
{%if gigi.typology == "typology2"> %}
   <div> {{gigi.name}}</div>
{% endif %}
</div>
```

Is this the only way? are there better DRY (dont repeat yourself) ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code you currently have; though, you could make the following small adjustment and get rid of quite a bit of code.

Why not use the `gigi.typology` string as the `id`?

```
{% for gigi in object_list %}
<div id="{{ gigi.typology }}"> 
   <div> {{gigi.name}}</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

If you are looking at having all the elements for a particular "typology" grouped together then you could also use the [`regroup`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) clause.

```
{% regoup object_list by typology as typolist %}
{% for typo in typolist %}
    <div id="{{ typo.grouper }}">
        {% for gigi in typo.list %}
        {{ gigi.name }}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What if I want to add some string to end of it?
I mean, <div id="{{gigi.typology}}_some_string"> How can we do it?

Comment: Have you not just answered your own question?

Comment: I’m sorry! I haven’t checked properly